# Returning a selected value from collection in Rails and sending it to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a database collection labeled `@joe`, and I am trying to pass the `id` variable into a link url path. This is in my `index.erb.html` file.

```
<%= select_tag "article", options_from_collection_for_select(@joe, 'id', 'title'), 
prompt: "Select Something" %>
```

In my articles_controller.rb file, I have

```
  def index
    @joe = Article.all
  end
```

I made a loop where it grabs each id number and passes it into the `article_url` path. I was wondering, in the dropdown box that I created above, when I select a certain value, I want to pass that value into the `article.id` variable. I'm having trouble with this and it outputs `x` amount of buttons.

```
<% @joe.each do |article| %>
    <%= button_to "SELECT", article_url(**parameter for article.id**), :method => 'get' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to go to this `articles_url` link (i.e. localhost:3000/articles/1, localhost:3000/articles/2), where the numbers represent the `id` values from the elements of the collection `@joe`. 
I was wondering if it is possible to do this or if I can implement JavaScript or jQuery into this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

And here's the rake routes command results:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
  home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)        home#index
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root GET    /                            home#index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @joe.each do |article| %>
    <%= button_to "SELECT", article_url(article) %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will call id on the article, and the article_url will be a get in this context

Why are you calling index parameter @joe?

Have you considered calling it @articles?

Comment: I know I was just trying to be unique. But won't this print out multiple buttons? `@joe` contains like `x` number of elements and when I tried this code, it just printed out `x` number of "SELECT" buttons.

Comment: That is what you are doing in the loop, adding a button per element in the collection.  As another programmer looking in, rails is all about conventions and ruby is about being expressive.  The '@joe' looks like a user to me or maybe an instance of a cup of coffee, '@articles' is much better if your goal is to have clear code.

Comment: But I don't want like 12 buttons displaying on the webpage. I just want one button where it goes to the `article_url` link where the `@joe id` is passed into the parameter. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but what you are talking about is not going to be something that will work out of the box.  You will need to write some javascript that will cause the buttons click to pull a variable from somewhere in your page.  If you are just getting started with this stuff i would encourage you to find a way to make the above work as it will be way easier on you.  To get the ids to the page you would just set '@articles' = Article.all.pluck(:id)